# Spring Integration Outbound Gateway is not encoding the URL

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I am using `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` to execute a rest service.My rest url contains few special characters like `#` and `&`. The exact url is `http://XXX70:12345/amisys-soa/rest/clientd/providers/professional/JAMPANA#1&?v=1&eao=02062017`

As per the Spring Integration specs, `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` should by default encode the url. So my expectation is that the above mentioned url should be transformed to  `http://XXX70:12345/amisys-soa/rest/clientd/providers/professional/JAMPANA%231%26?v=1&eao=02062017`

i.e `JAMPANA#1&` should be encoded as `JAMPANA%231%26`

But in reality, this not happening and the url is not at all encoded by `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

Why the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` is not encoding my url? Is there any workaround for my problem?

My `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`  is configured in the following manner:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                    http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                    encode-uri="true"
                                    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" >
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Some piece of the log is below:

```
2017-02-13 15:59:01,302 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Created GET request for "http://XXX70:12345/amisys-soa/rest/clientd/providers/professional/JAMPANA#1&?v=1&eao=02062017"
2017-02-13 15:59:01,302 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2017-02-13 15:59:01,858 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] GET request for "http://XXX70:12345/amisys-soa/rest/clientd/providers/professional/JAMPANA#1&?v=1&eao=02062017" resulted in 200 (OK)
2017-02-13 15:59:01,858 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@29569b73]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?`, `#` and `&` have special meaning in urls (start of query string, parameter separator and fragment start).

Since the url is loaded into a `UriComponents` object, these parts are separated out before encoding.

You will see, for example, that `%` is encoded properly.

Bottom line is you have to encode these special characters yourself; the framework can't tell if it's a query string or not.

Note that you will have to do all the encoding yourself, and turn off `encode-uri`; otherwise, you will get double encoding of, say, `%23`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification